# How to add custom data source to GeoServer WMS service?

Tags: gis, openlayers, geoserver

I'm installing GeoServer as a WMS server to cooperate with OpenLayers.

The trouble is that I have to use 3rd-party tile source which is provided through web service.
So I guess I have to tweak GeoServer to fetch tile image from 3rd-party server and response to OpenLayers request.

Is this idea correct? What should I do to accomplish that?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the 3rd party? OpenLayers already supports Google Maps and Bing Maps, so you could mash those images together in OpenLayers. Have you tried asking on the [GeoServer forum](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/GeoServer-f6100010.html)?

Answer (score 12):

You need to write a [GeoTools datastore](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/datastore.html) and then add that to GeoServer by dropping the jar into the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: Ian,Thanks for answering.I'll consider this idea.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Can you have a GeoTools datastore that represents image tiles?

Comment: Look at http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/index.html for starting points.

Answer (score 4):

If the 3rd party tiles are provided as a WMS, then you need [GeoServer cascading](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html)

> GeoServer has the ability to proxy a
>   remote Web Map Service (WMS). This
>   process is sometimes known as
>   **Cascading WMS**. Loading a remote WMS is
>   useful for many reasons. If you don’t
>   manage or have access to the remote
>   WMS, you can now manage its output as
>   if it were local. Even if the remote
>   WMS is not GeoServer, you can use
>   GeoServer features to treat its output
>   (watermarking, decoration, printing,
>   etc).

Comment: Mark,
Thanks for answering.
The 3rd party is not standard WMS,just a similar protocol. Is it possible to follow the cascading flow and add a custom protocol?

Comment: I don't know. One approach would be to make a proxy wrapper that presents the 3rd party tiles as a WMS.